# Permanent Weight Paint

Tags: weight-painting

[![*Permanent Weight Paint*][1]][1][image: *Points of Contact*]

I have a human metarig on a playermodel

I am having problems removing weight paint errors -> I am moving the armature and then editing the weight paint, yet some points of contact still do not go away (while editing w/ weight 0.0). They show up blue but move with the armature, so my playermodel is deformed.

Also some parts of the playermodel have weight paint that I cannot change and these do also move with the armature. I have seen this with the playermodel's teeth and ribs (they have a color of pure red, weight 1.0) but attempting to change teeth and rib weight paints and\or moving the armature then attempting to re-do the weight paint doesn't remove the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have to edit your vertex group.

1. go into edit mode and hit the vertex groups tab.
2. then see all of you vertex group and experiment by means of randomly selecting vertex groups by clicking the 'select' tab while in the vertex groups sections in the properties window.
3. when you see a mesh that has vertices scattered and not in the location you want them to be, click 'remove' tab so blender will erase all vertices that were assigned to that group.
4. next group the vertices that you want to  be grouped(do it logically).

ex: hand vertices grouped, then called 'hand verts'. Head vertices grouped and called 'head verts'(or whatever you prefer).

5. now that your veticies are logically grouped, go into weight paint mode and commence weight painting again. (your problem should be fixed).

p.s update me if that doesn't work, or if your having issues.

happy blending!